# How to initialise MySQL data in a replicated stateful

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a persistent MySQL database on a Kubernetes Cluster following this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/). I am trying to create the tables on initialization but cant get it to work.

I tried two different approaches.

First creating a new Config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-initdb-config
data:
  initdb.sql: |
    #SQL GOES HERE
```

And I added it to the volumes here with the stateful service (the commented out lines are what I added):

```
      volumes:
        - name: conf
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: config-map
          configMap:
            name: mysql
#        - name: mysql-initdb
#          configMap:
#            name: mysql-initdb-config
```

I also tried add the SQL data into the current config map in use:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: thesis
  labels:
    app: mysql
data:
  primary.cnf: |
    [mysqld]
    log-bin
  replica.cnf: |
    [mysqld]
    super-read-only
  initdb.sql: |
#   SQL goes here
```

Once again referencing it in the stateful set:

```
      volumes:
        - name: conf
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: config-map
          configMap:
            name: mysql
#        - name: mysql-initdb
#          configMap:
#            name: mysql;
```

Am I taking the complete wrong approach or is there just a small mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a mysql container is started for the first time, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and sql.sz that are found in **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** after creating a new database. So we have to mount the initialization script on that specific directory.

First create a new configmap/secret that will be used as volume source.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-initdb-config
data:
  initdb.sql: |
    #SQL GOES HERE
```

Then create a volume that will be mounted in  **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** directory.

```
  volumes:
    - name: init-script
      configMap:
        name: mysql-initdb-config
```

Now mount this volume on  the specific directory.

```
  volumeMounts:
    - name: init-script
      mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Further read: [How to use MySQL image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Comment: So that gives me this error: 'Warning  FailedCreate      2m21s (x16 over 5m5s)  statefulset-controller  create Pod mysql-0 in StatefulSet mysql failed error: Pod "mysql-0" is invalid: spec.containers[1].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "init-script"'

Comment: But that is definetly a helpful move in the right direction, I should hopefully be able to get it working from here.

Comment: can you check if the init-script volume is created or not? I think it's because the volumeMount couldn't find any volume having the name init-script.

Comment: Correct: "Warning  FailedMount       51s (x9 over 2m59s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "init-script" : configmap "mysql-initdb-config" not found"

Comment: Actually your original solution worked, I just got held up by a namespace error